# What is the correct way to calculate performance metrics when using KFold CV or Stratified CV?

Tags: python, keras, cross-validation, metrics, confusion-matrix

After reading a few tutorials, this is the first time I have built a Keras Deep Learning Model as I am a beginner in machine learning and deep learning. Most of the tutorials use the train-test split to train and test the model. However, I chose to use StratifiedKFold CV. The code is as below.

```
X = dataset[:,0:80].astype(float)
Y = dataset[:,80]
kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10,random_state=seed)
for train, test in kfold.split(X, Y):
   # create model
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Dense())
  model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
  model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='Adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
  model.fit(X[train], Y[train], epochs=100,batch_size=128, verbose=0)
  scores = model.evaluate(X[test], Y[test], verbose=1)
  print("%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
  cvscores.append(scores[1] * 100)
print("%.2f%% (+/- %.2f%%)" % (numpy.mean(cvscores), numpy.std(cvscores)))

Y[pred]= model.predict(X[test])
acc = accuracy_score(Y[test],Y[pred])
confusion = confusion_matrix(Y[test], Y[pred])
print(confusion)
plot_confusion_matrix(confusion, classes =['No','Yes'],title='Confusion Matrix')
TP= confusion[1,1]
TN= confusion[0,0]
FP= confusion[0,1]
FN= confusion[1,0]
print('Accuracy: ')
print((TP + TN) / float(TP + TN + FP + FN))
print(accuracy_score(Y[test],Y[pred]))

fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(Y[test], y_pred_prob)
plt.plot(fpr, tpr)

print(roc_auc_score(y_test, y_pred_prob))

y_pred_class = binarize([y_pred_prob], 0.3)[0]

confusion_new = confusion_matrix(Y[test], y_pred_class)
print(confusion_new)
```

I have understood the theoretical concept of Kfold CV and StratifiedKFoldCV. I have come across [What does KFold in python exactly do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36063014/what-does-kfold-in-python-exactly-do), [KFolds Cross Validation vs train_test_split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49134338/kfolds-cross-validation-vs-train-test-split), and a few more links. But when I calculate the performance metrics it gives me the following errors.

```
NameError: name 'pred' is not defined
NameError: name 'y_pred_prob' is not defined
NameError: name 'roc_curve' is not defined
```

What I am doing wrong here? Why am I getting these errors? How do I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: None of those variables are created in the code you've provided, so how can you expect to use them? You have `Y[pred]` but have not defined `pred`. You are using `y_pred_prob` in a function call, but you haven't imported or defined a function called `roc_curve` nor a variable called `y_pred_prob`

Comment: okay. I get it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way you can try:

```
X = dataset[:,0:80].astype(float)
Y = dataset[:,80]

# define model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(10))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='Adam',metrics=['accuracy'])

# create folds
folds = list(StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=1).split(X, Y))

# train model for every fold
for j, (train_idx, val_idx) in enumerate(folds):

    print('\nFold ',j)
    X_train_cv = X[train_idx]
    y_train_cv = Y[train_idx]
    X_valid_cv = X[val_idx]
    y_valid_cv= Y[val_idx]

    model.fit(X_train_cv, 
              y_train_cv, 
              epochs=100,
              batch_size=128, 
              validation_data = (X_valid_cv, y_valid_cv),
              verbose=0)

    print(model.evaluate(X_valid_cv, y_valid_cv))

    # check metrics for each fold
    pred = model.predict(X_valid_cv)
    acc = accuracy_score(y_valid_cv, pred)
    confusion = confusion_matrix(y_valid_cv, pred)
    print(confusion)
```

Comment: What is X_valid_cv and y_valid_cv? Is it same as X_test_cv and y_test_cv?

Comment: The code calculates the confusion matrix for all the fold. What if one wants to compute the final confusion matrix after completing 10 fold cv? How can one do that and plot a AUC-ROC curve?